# How to block/unblock Skype FileTransfer without Skype API?

Tags: block, file-transfer, skype

Need to find a way to block/unblock File transfer from Skype possibly without restarting the Skype.

If the solutions is to block or filter the packets it is acceptable but need the how-to explanation.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it will be necessary to quit Skype for turning File Transfer off or on. Details about how this can be done can be found here: http://slks.co.th/blog/?p=737

Check it out.